Loop Through Complex ACF Repeater and Group Fields in WordPress
I'm working with Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) in WordPress, and I'm having trouble correctly looping through a complex repeater and group field structure to display the data on my site.
Does anyone have an idea how to solve this issue or maybe faced similar issue before?
Here is the structure of my ACF fields:

"locations" (Repeater field)

"country" (Group field)

"country_name" (Text field)

"country_locations" (Repeater field)

"city" (Group field)

"city_name" (Text field)

"city_company_name" (Text field)

"city_image" (Image field)










I want to display the data on the front end in a layout like this:
<div>
    <h2>country_name1</h2>
    <div>
        <h4>city_name1</h4>
        <h5>city_company_name1</h5>        
        <img city_image1/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h4>city_name2</h4>
        <h5>city_company_name2</h5>        
        <img city_image2/>
    </div>
</div>

I have tried various ways to loop through each Repeater fields, but with no luck, I only got the Country names.
<?php if (have_rows('locations')) : ?>
        <?php while (have_rows('locations')) : the_row(); ?>
            <?php $country = get_sub_field('country'); ?>
            <div>
                <h2>Country Name: <?php echo $country['country_name']; ?></h2>
                <?php if (have_rows('country_locations', 'country')) : ?>
                    <?php while (have_rows('country_locations', 'country')) : the_row(); ?>
                        <?php $city = get_sub_field('city'); ?>
                        <div>
                            <h4>City: <?php echo $city['city_name']; ?></h4>
                            <h5>Company: <?php echo $city['city_company_name']; ?></h5>

                            <?php if ($city['city_image']) : ?>
                                <div>
                                    <img src="<?php echo $city['city_image']['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $city['city_image']['alt']; ?>" />
                                </div>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </div>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>


(have_rows('country_locations', 'country')) remove country. The second parameter is for post_id not a string. The documentation for have_rows is pretty close to what you have.
